# General Solution to update Entity States by comparing original and modified graph EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, ef-core-3.1

I am pretty much sure there will be a solution to this problem already. But as I am new to this, so I am not able to find the appropriate one.

The problem is straightforwardly a realtime one. I have a complex object with multiple child objects, and maybe grandchild(ren), and even more complex as collections under child(ren) objects. Literally this can be an n-level object with mixes of 1-1 or 1-M objects and collections.

In the Asp.Net core Razor Pages context, the graph is requested by the client by an Identifier, the server fetches the whole object graph using EF Core .Include() and the whole graph is sent to client in the response. A user on the client browser makes changes in the form of updates, deletes both in 1-1 and 1-M properties. And then hit save to save the changes.

The modified data is sent to the server and I first fetch the existing graph from database, then traverse every object/collection in the modified graph, compare the data for changes using [CompareNetObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/), or check for new/deleted objects, mark entity-states accordingly, pass the graph to EF Core db-context and the changes took place in the database. All good!

Now I want to know if there is a general solution that can do all this **painting the state** thing in itself out of the box? As I am working on an enterprise application, and writing the painting logic for every graph is just not looking maintainable. Or maybe there is already a mature solution for this which I don't want to miss.

I looked [TrackableEntities](https://github.com/TrackableEntities) but that is dependent on sending the state from client. I don't think this is doable in Web apps.

I am looking for a solution like [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff) but they are saying [it does not have support for EF Core yet](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff/issues/164).

Comment: it should work with the normal EF core change tracking. You get the object again, and then insert all values from the client, and then you look in your changeset. Values that were the same should be ignored and not give any updates in the database when you commitchanges.

Comment: Can you please explain "insert all values from the client" as this is the major area that I want to generalize for every kind of graph. What about the collection entries which are deleted?